# Make CSS comments act as links inside CSS file

Tags: css, netbeans, text-editor

Is it possible in netbeans to make CSS comments act as links inside a CSS file? for faster navigation inside the file...

e.g. clicking on "4. Media Queries" below would jump to e.g. line 687 of the css file

```
/* 1.  Layout  */
/* 2.  Generic */
/* 3.  Header & Footer */
/* 4.  Media Queries */
/* ... */
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too bad it is not possible, but there is a better workflow you can use

http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/vLZrgq

```
/* 1.  Layout  */
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}   


/* 2.  Generic */
h1{font-size:1em;}

......
......
```

What you can do is by adding the comments right before your codes, so that everytime you want to navigate to that particular section, you just need to use your IDE and search for that particular comments.